# Counting Cells in Columns Depending on Content

Tags: excel

I have a column with 5 or so categories each described by a string of text.  If I take a =Count function it won't count anything because they're text strings, and if I use Counta I'll only get the count for one of the five categories by highlighting that category specifically.   Is there a way to, with or without filtering, create a counting function that - when dragged down - takes the whole column as input and then automatically sorts the counts by 'blocks'?  Would it make more sense to do this using a VLOOKUP?  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Use COUNTIF()

for example:

**=COUNTIF(A1:A100,B1)**  which will count the number of cells in column A containing the text in B1